# How to make del work for my own classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can use `del` to delete a slice from a list. For example

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
del a[0:4:2]
print(a)
```

The output is

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

My question is what method is being called on `a` here, and what would I have to do to make `del a[0:4:2]` work for an object of a custom class?

I tried this:

```
class Spam:
    def __delslice__(self, i, j):
        print('Slice deleted')

a = Spam()
del a[1:3]
```

but this gave me the error message `TypeError: 'Spam' object does not support item deletion`. In any case, `__delslice__` only has two arguments (apart from `self`) whereas it would need 3 for a call like `del a[0:4:2]` to make sense.

I also tried this:

```
class Spam:
def __delitem__(self, item):
    print('item deleted')

a = Spam()
del a[1:3]
```

and it printed `item deleted`, whereas I would expect it to print `item deleted` twice (because the slice `[1:3]` contains two indices `1` and `2`).

Can somebody explain what is going on?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Is it possible to reopen this question and/or link to a question with a python 3.x answer? The answers given there use `xrange` and `print` as a keyword. Also they don't mention `__delslice__` at all.

Comment: `__delslice__` does not exist in Python 3.  `del obj[i:j]` is syntactic sugar for `obj.__delitem__(slice(i, j, None))`.  You need to check the argument to `__delitem__` to see if it is a slice object  (`isinstance(item, slice)`) and handle it accordingly.  The answers to the linked question make this clear.  As for it being for Python 2 rather than Python 3, surely you can translate things like `xrange` to `range` and `print` as a statement to `print` as a function.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Forgive my ignorance - I only started learning Python yesterday, so I'm a completer beginner. I'm really hoping to get into it, and i'd like SO to help, but it's going to be very annoying if all of my questions are closed within 5 minutes. The answer in that linked question only takes me so far. I tried `def __delitem__(self, i): if isinstance(i, slice): for j in range(i.start, i.stop, i.step): print('item deleted')` but it seems `i.step` is `None` when I use `a.del[1:3]`.

Comment: `slice` objects have an optional third argument for `step`.  If it is `None` you need to interpret it according to the conventions of your class.  It's common to interpret a `step` of `None` to be `1`, but that is up to you.  It's even more common to never have to implement your own sequence so questions like this don't come up very often.

Comment: I think you last comment would make a good, new question that wouldn't be closed.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ok, I've got it working now. Thank you for your help. I'll delete the question in a couple of minutes.

Comment: I would advise against deleting the question.  Duplicate questions provide a hook for some people to find the right question.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ok. It stays. Thanks again for your help.